# Get client windows login user name from request using node or express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working for a project which uses windows login credentials authentication mechanism for user validation using node/express js. Previously we did same kind of authentication using request.getRemoteUser() to retrieve client windows user name in java in previous project. Here my question is how to retrieve client windows user name using node/express js?. Is there any predefined module to do that?. Please help.

Comment: Is there any server you specifically working with to do the authentication? like `azure` or `fire-base`

Comment: we are using IIS node as server

Comment: Then you probably check if your request object has windows authentication token. if not that might be the issue.

Comment: I think Passport module in express js mentioned by Paul may work for me, i am exploring it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) with express, you can use a [Windows Authentication Strategy](https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth) with it.